# Get-ADUser not recognized

Tags: powershell, file, directory, syntax-error, ou

I'm trying to write a script for Powershell that will display the date/time of last login and date/time of last password change for every user and separate the data according to their Organizational Unit within Active Directory.

I'm getting a number of errors, including one that says `Get-ADUser` isn't even recognized as a command. Any thoughts?  Here's my script:

```sh
$my=get-credential

get-aduser -filter "name -like * -searchbase 'OU=students,OU=Users,OU=GBNetworkLabs,DC=gbnetworklabs,DC=local'"
-properties * -server gbnetworklabs.local -credential $my | select -property name, lastlogondate, passwordlastset
```

I've also tried
`import-module activedirectory`
but get errors with that too.

Here are some of the parameters I've been given:

> Users='OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=GBNetworkLabs,DC=gbnetworklabs,DC=local'
>   Servers='OU=Powershell,OU=VDI,OU=GBNetworkLabs,DC=gbnetworklabs,DC=local'

Any and all help is appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Before you can run AD cmdlets you must, as you've shown, run `import-module activedirectory` - what error are you running into when running this?

Comment: The ActiveDirectory PowerShell module is not installed by default. If you're on a Server OS, it's a feature that can be installed from Server Manager. On Client OSes, it is part of a package called RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) and may either be a separately downloadable installer or a Windows optional feature depending on the OS version.

Comment: Hi Matthew, this is the error I keep getting:```import-module : The specified module 'activedirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ import-module activedirectory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (activedirectory:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ryan, I'll see if I can use RSAT!

Answer (score 17):

If you need the Active Directory Powershell cmdlets on Windows 10 later verisons they can be installed as follows:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS*"} | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```